# PHP array will only loop out two rows, overwriting the second row/index subsequently

Tags: php, arrays, object, dictionary, foreach

I get a FORM POST and on the button pressed (submitted) there is a value (primary key) of the item in the database ($artid).

For each of these POSTs I try and add a new object value into an array mapped to a key set by $artid, so it should be unique. The array is added to a $_SESSION to get the same array out each time.

The first object is added fine, but other objects just overwrites the second position in the array. I need it to continue to grow.

Code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['itemArray'])) {
    ...
    $cartArr = array();
    $bookitem = new BookItem($artid, $qty, $price);
    $cartArr[$artid] = $bookitem;

    $_SESSION['itemArray'] = $cartArr;

    foreach($cartArr as $key => $obj) { ....   }
}
else {
    $cartArr = $_SESSION['itemArray'];
    if (array_key_exists($artid, $cartArr)) {
        $cartArr[$artid]->quantity = $qty; 
    }
    else {
        $bookitem = new BookItem($artid, $qty, $price);
        $cartArr[$artid] = $bookitem;
    }
    foreach($cartArr as $key => $obj) { ...   } 
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like your setting the Session array back once you add the new element.  So the next time the page loads the new value wasn't saved.

You have 2 options:

1) after your foreach set `$_SESSION['itemArray'] = $cartArr;`  this will save any changes (such as adding a new element) in session.

2) Assign `$cartArr`to be a reference to `$_SESSION['itemArray']` so that any changes made to `$cartArr` are actually made to `$_SESSION['itemArray']`  You would do this by `$cartArr =& $_SESSION['itemArray'];` right after your `else`

Answer (score 1):

Can you go into more detail on what happens in your foreach? Are you assigning class properties to your array?

Also, you might try serializing your array before assigning it to a session value.

If all else fails, this usually helps me realize where I am going wrong:

```
print_r($cartArr);
```

Good Luck!

EDIT:
After looking at another answer, I realized that I also overlooked the early assigning of your session variable. You will need to assign that after your foreach, or like Ben said - the work done by your foreach is not going to carry over. (I would still serialize the array though)

Comment: I changed to using `var_dump()` and haven't looked back.